# How to use mutate() and ifelse() to create a column based on a match or multiple matches in different data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, tibble

I want to join one data frame (df) with multiple rows on the condition that there is a match for **datatossedtest$StationID** in **datasummary$StationID** (see below). I then need certain columns from the rows with matches in the **datatossedtest** data frame to be condensed into one column in the **datasummary** data frame.

Test data:

```
datatossedtest <- tibble(`WID` = c("10A", "11A", "11A", "12A", "10A"), `StationID` = c("A", "B", "B", "AB", "C"), `Issue` = c("Bad", "Not Good", "Bad", "Meh", "Meh"), 'n' = c(7, 3, 6, 5, 4))

datasummary <- tibble(`WID` = c("10A", "11A","12A", "10A", "13A"), `StationID` = c("A", "B","AB","C","D"))
```

I tried using mutate() and glue() to do this but since there isn't a one-to-one match, I am running into issues.

```
datasummary <- datasummary %>% 
  mutate(comment = ifelse(datasummary$StationID %in% datatossedtest$StationID, glue("{datatossedtest$n} sample(s) were thrown out because of {datatossedtest$Issue}"),"Lookin good"))
```

This is my output for the above code:

```
> datasummary
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  WID   StationID comment                                        
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>                                          
1 10A   A         7 sample(s) were thrown out because of Bad     
2 11A   B         3 sample(s) were thrown out because of Not Good
3 12A   AB        6 sample(s) were thrown out because of Bad     
4 10A   C         5 sample(s) were thrown out because of Meh     
5 13A   D         Lookin good
```

While this is very close to what I want, I need all variations of "issues" from **datatossedtest** with **StationID** matches to **datasummary** to also be included in the comment column. Please see my desired output below.

```
> datasummary
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  WID   StationID comment                                        
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>                                          
1 10A   A         7 sample(s) were thrown out because of Bad     
2 11A   B         3 sample(s) were thrown out because of Not Good AND 6 sample(s) were thrown out because of Bad
3 12A   AB        6 sample(s) were thrown out because of Bad     
4 10A   C         5 sample(s) were thrown out because of Meh     
5 13A   D         Lookin good
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a [join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html) for this.

The join will give you one row for every match (so WID 11A, Station B will have 2 rows), which you can combine back into one row per WID/StationID using `group_by`/`summarise`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

datatossedtest <- tibble(`WID` = c("10A", "11A", "11A", "12A", "10A"), `StationID` = c("A", "B", "B", "AB", "C"), `Issue` = c("Bad", "Not Good", "Bad", "Meh", "Meh"), 'n' = c(7, 3, 6, 5, 4))

datasummary <- tibble(`WID` = c("10A", "11A","12A", "10A", "13A"), `StationID` = c("A", "B","AB","C","D"))

datasummary %>%
    left_join(datatossedtest, by = c("WID", "StationID")) %>%
    mutate(comment = ifelse(is.na(n), "Lookin good", paste(n, "sample(s) were thrwon out because of", Issue))) %>%
    select(WID, StationID, comment) %>%
    group_by(WID, StationID) %>%
    summarise(comment = paste(comment, collapse = " AND ")) %>%
    ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'WID'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   WID   StationID comment                                                       
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>                                                         
#> 1 10A   A         7 sample(s) were thrwon out because of Bad                    
#> 2 10A   C         4 sample(s) were thrwon out because of Meh                    
#> 3 11A   B         3 sample(s) were thrwon out because of Not Good AND 6 sample(…
#> 4 12A   AB        5 sample(s) were thrwon out because of Meh                    
#> 5 13A   D         Lookin good
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>